# Will nights be cold along the route from Perth to Melbourne at the end of November?

Tags: australia, weather-and-climate

In a few days I'll be hitchhiking across Australia from Perth to Melbourne (and then up to Sydney).

Now I've heard it can get surprisingly cold in the outback at night. But I don't know if that's just in the centre or just in the cold season.

Most people I would imagine would include the Nullarbor Plain as being in the Outback. But it's also on the coast.

I know it's already hot in the cities in Australia so I'm expecting this route to be be 40C+ during the day, but should I expect warm or cold nights?

Comment: It isn't going to be 40+ yet on the costal route

Comment: @Calchas: Really? It is already in Sydney, but I guess that's a bit further north even if less deserty.

Comment: [You should bring a jacket](http://www.weatherzone.com.au/climate/station.jsp?lt=site&lc=18106)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely to be about 10C at overnight. It might be a little cooler before dawn.

Comment: Indeed it was! We had three chilly nights in our tent across the Nullarbor and nearby areas in the south. Cheapo sleeping bags with a couple of extra layers of clothes was enough though. Still colder than I expected before asking the question here!